# Gradle Version 6.7.1 - Upgrade Failed

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, build.gradle

I have upgraded my Android Studio to 4.2 version few hours ago, and now when I opened one of my old projects I got a message from Android studio to upgrade Gradle version to 6.7.1. After I did that I got this error message and I can't build my project anymore... I also tried provided solutions from Android Studio, but with no success. Any help?

[image]

[image]

Error:

> Unable to find method ''void
> com.android.build.api.extension.AndroidComponentsExtension$DefaultImpls.androidTest$default(com.android.build.api.extension.AndroidComponentsExtension,
> com.android.build.api.extension.VariantSelector,
> kotlin.jvm.functions.Function1, int, java.lang.Object)'' 'void
> com.android.build.api.extension.AndroidComponentsExtension$DefaultImpls.androidTest$default(com.android.build.api.extension.AndroidComponentsExtension,
> com.android.build.api.extension.VariantSelector,
> kotlin.jvm.functions.Function1, int, java.lang.Object)'
>
> Gradle's dependency cache may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after
> a network connection timeout.)
>
> Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network) The state
> of a Gradle build process (daemon) may be corrupt. Stopping all Gradle
> daemons may solve this problem.
>
> Stop Gradle build processes (requires restart) Your project may be
> using a third-party plugin which is not compatible with the other
> plugins in the project or the version of Gradle requested by the
> project.
>
> In the case of corrupt Gradle processes, you can also try closing the
> IDE and then killing all Java processes.

Comment: `./gradlew build -s` in the terminal run this command

Comment: @UsamaAltaf '.' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: @UsamaAltaf What exact path do I need to add in my Enviromental variables on Windows? I cannot execute that command yet.

Comment: leave it just try to change the gradle distribution version from gradle wrapper properties

Comment: To what version exactly, can you be more specific? @UsamaAltaf

Comment: I was having same issue and turned out it was due to an issue with `gradle-play-publisher` plugin. Fix outlined in this [Github Issue](https://github.com/Triple-T/gradle-play-publisher/issues/947#issuecomment-843634852)

Comment: this solution work with me [stackoverflow.com/a/70584130/5112812](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70584130/5112812) I hope this help

Comment: this solution work with me [stackoverflow.com/a/70584130/5112812](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70584130/5112812) I hope this help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

if you us dagger hilt change the version of dagger hilt

Using a combination of

Hilt version 2.35
Android Studio version 4.2
Android Gradle Plugin version 4.2.0
Gradle version to 6.7.1

worked for me

documentaire https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/2337

Comment: I am using a canary version of the android studio but this is not working for me when I am adding the hilt plugin only when I am getting this same error. Any Idea What we can do for this

Answer (score 5):

This solution from the Dagger Github solved it for me.
https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/2337

```
repositories {
        /*  ...  */
         maven {
            url  "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots"
            content {
                includeModule("com.google.dagger", "hilt-android-gradle-plugin")
            }
        }
}

    dependencies {
       
        classpath "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-gradle-plugin:HEAD-SNAPSHOT"
        
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that your dependencies have the same version on both project level and module level Gradle files.
I've this issue in my project level Gradle when I was updating Hilt version. I've updated the version to 2.35 in module level but forgot to update it in project-level Gradle. It worked for me when I update it in both.

```
classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your gradle version to 7.0.0-alpha15

This worked for me after I tried all the other suggestions here.