# Unable to find method ''void com.android.build.api.extension.AndroidComponentsExtension$DefaultImpls.androidTest$default(com.android.build

Tags: android, kotlin

my first project using Jetpack Compose got an error like this, how can I fix it

> Unable to find method ''void
> com.android.build.api.extension.AndroidComponentsExtension$DefaultImpls.androidTest$default(com.android.build.api.extension.AndroidComponentsExtension,
> com.android.build.api.extension.VariantSelector,
> kotlin.jvm.functions.Function1, int, java.lang.Object)'' 'void
> com.android.build.api.extension.AndroidComponentsExtension$DefaultImpls.androidTest$default(com.android.build.api.extension.AndroidComponentsExtension,
> com.android.build.api.extension.VariantSelector,
> kotlin.jvm.functions.Function1, int, java.lang.Object)' Gradle's
> dependency cache may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network
> connection timeout.)

My dependencies:

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.0-beta03'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.4.30"
        classpath "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-gradle-plugin:2.31.2-alpha"
    }
```

Answer (score 68):

In my case the problem was incompatibility between Android Gradle Plugin and Hilt library. After upgrading Hilt to the latest version, I can also use the latest AGP.

**[EDIT]**
It seems that recent release of Android Gradle Plugin has fixed the issue and
AGP version `7.0.0-beta05` works with Hilt version `2.37`.

[Link to related Github issue](https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/2700#issuecomment-873259257)

Answer (score 30):

In my case `AGP 7.0.0` builded successfully with `Hilt 2.37`

Comment: for me it worked with Kotlin version 1.5.21 AGP 7.0.0 and Hilt 2.38.1. 

But now it warns about Kotlin plugin version. Its weird because on marketplace there is already kotlin plugin version 1.5.21 and it does not let me upgrade the old plugin

Answer (score 24):

If you are using Hilt, upgrade it to v2.38.1 .
Some problems with AGP 7 has been fixed in this release

See here : https://github.com/google/dagger/releases

Answer (score 11):

For me, I was used

**Gradle**

```
classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.3"
classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.5.31"
```

**Hilt**

Projet level gradle

```
classpath "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-gradle-plugin:2.39.1"
```

App level gradle

```
implementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.39.1"
kapt "com.google.dagger:hilt-compiler:2.39.1"
androidTestImplementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-testing:2.39.1"
kaptAndroidTest "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.39.1"
```

Answer (score 7):

**[UPDATE]**: Currently, u can use `Hilt 2.38` with `gradle:7.1.0`

```
dependencies {
  classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.0'
  classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.5.10"
  classpath "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-gradle-plugin:2.37"
}
```

if it doesn't work, let me know

Answer (score 6):

use the gradle plugin for Hilt **2.39.1**:

```
classpath 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android-gradle-plugin:2.39.1'
```

and update the hilt version to **2.37**:

```
implementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.37"
kapt "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.37"
```

Answer (score 5):

just update to latest version of dagger hilt i,e, currently(2.38.1)

Comment: can you add the AGP & kotlin that you are using please?

Comment: hilt_version = '2.39.1' , AGP = '7.0.4', kotlin_version = '1.5.31'

Comment: I ended up with the following settings hilt_version = '2.40.5' , AGP = '7.0.4', kotlin_version = '1.5.31'

Answer (score 4):

Updating hilt version to latest worked for me.

```
def hilt_version = '2.39.1'
```

Answer (score 3):

Use Android Gradle plugin (AGP) version `7.0.3` +, for instance `7.1.0-rc01` or `7.2.0-alpha06`

check in project level build gradle config

```
plugins {
    id("com.android.application") version "7.0.4" apply false
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android") version "1.6.10" apply false
    id("com.android.library") version "7.0.4" apply false
}


buildscript {

    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.4")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this dependency to your build.gradle file

```
classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.1"
classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.8'
classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:10.4.0"
classpath "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-gradle-plugin:2.35"
classpath "androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:2.3.5"
```

Answer (score 1):

I was faced this same issue here is my changes

- kotlin_version = "1.6.10" // was "1.5.21"
- hilt_version = '2.39.1' // was "2.37"
- gradle 7.1.0-rc01

Answer (score 1):

My app works now when I updated them:

```
com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.2

distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.4-bin.zip

com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.42
```

Answer (score 0):

in my solution , this work fine

- kotlin_version = "1.6.10"
- gradle-7.3
- gradle:7.0.4 ( plugin )
- com.google.dagger:hilt-android-gradle-plugin:2.37**